# Magento Possible to get Grand Total of Wishlish Items

Tags: magento

Is there a simple way/function to receive the Grand Total of the products in the wishlist?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work

```
public function getWishListTotal($customer) {
$wishList = Mage::getSingleton('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customer);
$wishListItemCollection = $wishList->getItemCollection();

$wishListTotal=0;
foreach ($wishListItemCollection as $_item) {
    $_product = $_item->getProduct();

    $wishListTotal = $wishListTotal + $_product->getPrice()
}

return $wishListTotal;   
}
```

This is for the price total of items on the wishlist, without taxes, shipping etc.